# Creating a Visual Studio property sheet to ease the use of a C++ library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, libraries

I am building a C++ library (set of headers, import libs and DLLs).  I want to make using this library as easy as possible for any developer who wants to use it.  Especially I don't want the consumers of this library to have to worry about changing the header paths, libraries paths and link libraries manually for all the different configurations of their project (Debug|Release and x86/x64/ARM).  I know that I can do this using property sheets.  I created 6 different property sheets for this purpose (one for each configuration).  Each sheet looks like the below (listing just the x86|Debug version, assume that the macros INCLUDEPATH and LIBPATH are correctly defined):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_PropertySheetDisplayName>MyCPPLib, 1.0</_PropertySheetDisplayName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$INCLUDEPATH;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(AdditionalLibraryDirectories);$LIBPATH\x86\Debug</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>MyCPPLib.lib;$(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

I want to know if it possible to create just a single props file that can take care of all 6 configurations based on whatever is the user's active configuration?
How would that file look like?

Comment: Do keep in mind that it is possible (even likely) for someone to define more than just the standard "Release" and "Debug" configurations. I know several projects which define custom configurations to distinguish between building a static library versus building a .dll, for example.

Comment: @BillyONeal Sure.  I would be happy to just support the default two "Debug" and "Release" for my library.  I am new to this property sheet stuff.  Do you know how it would look like for these 6 conbinations?

Comment: Hmm, I did something like that a while ago. I'll try to remember to look it up tomorrow. The key to realize is that these are really just MSBuild files. And you can do conditions in plain MSBuild just fine (but I can't remember the syntax off-hand). I found that my property sheets became a lot simpler when I started treating the build configuration (debug/release) separately from the platform, rather than the silly "concatenate both into one string, and then use that to determine build settings" convention that exists in VS project files by default. :)

Comment: @RamanSharma: I would do what boost does and use automatic linking to solve this problem with your library. (See `#pragma comment(lib, "MyCPPLib")`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just install your library binaries in a structure such as:

```
<toplevelsdkdir>
  |-> lib
       |-> x86
            |-> Debug
            |-> Release
       |-> x64
            |-> Debug
            |-> Release
```

And then just create a single project-wide props file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_PropertySheetDisplayName>MyCPPLib, 1.0</_PropertySheetDisplayName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$INCLUDEPATH;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(AdditionalLibraryDirectories);$LIBPATH\$(PlatformTarget)\$(Configuration)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>MyCPPLib.lib;$(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

If you can want you can replace the variables INCLUDEPATH and LIBPATH with information read from the registry (where you can put it during installation):

```
<ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$([MSBuild]::GetRegistryValue(`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MyCompany\MySDK\v1`, `InstallDir`))\INCLUDE;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
</ClCompile>
```